# Multiple sections set as inline-block, when one of them has a line less text, it misaligns it

Tags: html, css

[image: misaligned section]

HTML:

`<section id="minibox"><h3>Shop</h3><i>The store module. Manage your products, payment methods and more.</i><br /><a title="Remove" href="#" style="float:right; margin:10px 0 0 10px;" class="content-btn-small">-</a><a href="#" style="float:right; margin:10px 0 0 0;" class="content-btn-small">Edit</a></section>`

`<section id="minibox"><h3>Comments</h3><i>The comment module. Allows comments on pages you choose.</i><br /><a title="Remove" href="#" style="float:right; margin:10px 0 0 10px;" class="content-btn-small">-</a><a href="#" style="float:right; margin:10px 0 0 0;" class="content-btn-small">Edit</a></section>`

`<section id="minibox"><h3>Other</h3><i>The store module. Manage your products, payment methods and more.</i><br /><a title="Remove" href="#" style="float:right; margin:10px 0 0 10px;" class="content-btn-small">-</a><a href="#" style="float:right; margin:10px 0 0 0;" class="content-btn-small">Edit</a></section>`

`<section id="minibox"><h3>Other</h3><i>Test module for layout testing purposes, more text to make the box larger to see how it handles it.</i><br /><a title="Remove" href="#" style="float:right; margin:10px 0 0 10px;" class="content-btn-small">-</a><a href="#" style="float:right; margin:10px 0 0 0;" class="content-btn-small">Edit</a></section>`

`<section id="minibox"><h3>Other</h3><i>Test module for layout testing purposes, more text to make the box larger to see how it handles it.</i><br /><a title="Remove" href="#" style="float:right; margin:10px 0 0 10px;" class="content-btn-small">-</a><a href="#" style="float:right; margin:10px 0 0 0;" class="content-btn-small">Edit</a></section>`

CSS:

`#minibox {
    width: 18%;
    margin: 10px 1%;
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #EEE;
    text-align:center;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height:142px;
}`

When one of the boxes has less text than the others it wasn't displaying inline, so I tried adding min-height / height thinking it would fix it. It makes all the box sizes coincide but it still knocks the one with less text down a line. Is there any way I can fix this without just adding an empty line?

Thanks

Comment: Please post the full html for all these blocks rather than just the block being pushed down.  Thanks.

Comment: An ID should be unique. You should use a class on each item to set your styles.

Comment: @AndyWarren Added all the section HTML, although it is just a copy and paste job with different test text.

Comment: @BillyMoat Whoops, slip up from me there. I'm still learning and that one always catches me out, thanks!

Comment: You could just set a height on the boxes. As long as you know they will always contain roughly the same text.

Comment: There is a height set, it didn't fix it, i've got it working now anyway, thanks though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: top` to your CSS. On a side note, consider using a class instead of an id for recurring styles.

Comment: Brilliant, all working now, thank you! I'll remember that one for future, i've had this problem before. I've got the minibox as a class now too!